# JavaScript doesn't recognize JSX despite React being imported -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn React but I ran into an issue where after I installed React, React Dom, and Bable with npm, I couldn't import these libraries without getting an error.

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react"
import Header from "./cp1-header"
import Footer from "./cp1-footer"

function Page() {
    return(
    <div>
        <h1>Take a look at these Descriptions</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>Why I love React.js: </li>
            <li>Thanks for watching </li>
            <li>Make sure to like comment and subscribe </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<div><Header/><Page/><Footer/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**The error was: cannot use import statement outside of module**. I tried fixing this error by setting the type in the package.json to module but that didn't change anything. I instead updated my import statements:

```
const React =  require("react");
const ReactDOM =  require("react-dom");
const Header =  require("./cp1-header");
const Footer =  require("./cp1-footer");
```

**This lead me to another error where javascript couldn't identify the bracket tags in my code.** It wasn't able to understand Babel I assume. I tried to fix this by setting the script type = "text/babel" and linking the babel library but that **throws another error stating require is not defined.**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cp1.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "root"></div>
        <script src = "cp1.js" type = "text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I undoed my work and feel stuck. This is the current state of my work:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "cp1.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "root"></div>
        <script src = "cp1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react"
import Header from "./cp1-header"
import Footer from "./cp1-footer"

function Page() {
    return(
    <div>
        <h1>Take a look at these Descriptions</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>Why I love React.js: </li>
            <li>Thanks for watching </li>
            <li>Make sure to like comment and subscribe </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<div><Header/><Page/><Footer/></div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**cp1-footer**

```
import React from "react";

function Footer() {
    return(
        <div>"20ccc@Development Rights Reseved 2022</div>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

**cp1-header**

```
import React from "react";

function Header(){
    return(
        <nav className = "nav">
            <img src = "https://www.sportsengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/react-logo-570x570.png" className = "img"></img>
            <ul className = "items">
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Sign In</li>
                <li>Sign Up</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header
```

**package json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "cp1-footer.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

How do I make this app work? I feel entirely lost

Comment: You have to preprocess the files with `babel`, simple installing it doesn't do anything. If you are a beginner please use `create-react-app` or `vite` with `React`, because the things you are trying to do are pretty advanced.

Comment: I tried creating a react app; however, it gave me the same import error

Comment: How did you run that react app?

Comment: I ran it with VS Code's live server and npm start.

Comment: You shouldn't use VS Code's live server. `npm start` should be enough. You were probably creating two servers and used the wrong one.

Comment: okay thank you for the help. Let me try using npm start only

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix the import error by going to the package.json and adding  `"type":"module"` as a property.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "cp1-footer.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```